# Как сделать такую переменную?

Tags: css, веб-программирование, scss

Хочу сделать такую переменную, что если я в классе писал скажем вот так `<div class="fs-18">text</div>` то нужно чтобы это вот число он сам подставлял в font-size. Подскажите, возможно ли это сделать и если да, то как?

Comment: Насколько я знаю, автоматически нельзя, используется просто объявление кучи классов с нужными размерами.

Answer (score 1):

Можно задействовать CSS-переменную:

```css
.fs {
  font-size: var(--fs);
}
```

```html
<div class="fs" style="--fs: 16px">Text</div>
<div class="fs" style="--fs: 20px">Text</div>
<div class="fs" style="--fs: 24px">Text</div>
<div class="fs" style="--fs: 28px">Text</div>
<div class="fs" style="--fs: 32px">Text</div>
```

Хотя, с таким же успехом, можно сразу вписать font-size в style. Целесообразность подхода зависит от того, будет ли участвовать переменная еще в каких-либо вычислениях.

Либо, как отметил @OliverPatterson, определять каждый класс:

```css
.fs-16 { font-size: 16px; }
.fs-20 { font-size: 20px; }
.fs-24 { font-size: 24px; }
```

```html
<div class="fs-16">Text</div>
<div class="fs-20">Text</div>
<div class="fs-24">Text</div>
```

Comment: Если нужно, могу скинуть вариант с `fs` классами от 1 до 100. Легко же сгенерировать)

Comment: давайте) Буду рад

Comment: `for(let i = 1; i < 101; i++) { element.innerHTML += '.fs-${i} { font-size: ${i}px; }\n'; }` - только кавычки обратные.

Answer (score -1):

Ну можно вот так:

```js
let fontSizeEls = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="fs-"]')

for (let i = 0; i < fontSizeEls.length; i++) {
  let fontSizeEl = fontSizeEls[i]
  let classes = fontSizeEl.className.split(' ')

  for (let j = 0; j < classes.length; j++) {
    let currentClass = classes[j]

    if(currentClass.match(/^fs\-\d+$/) !== null) {
      let fontSize = currentClass.split('-')[1]

      fontSizeEl.style.fontSize = fontSize + 'px'
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="fs-10">text</div>
<div class="fs-25">text</div>
<div class="fs-42">text</div>
<div class="fs-50">text</div>
<div class="fs-75">text</div>
<div class="fs-100">text</div>
```

#### Объяснение

Сначала по селектору выбираем все элементы у которых в атрибуте `class`, есть `fs-`, дальше проходимся по этим самым элементам, а уже на каждой итерации проходимся по классам, если класс начинается и заканчивается на `fs-КАКОЕТОЧИСЛО`, тогда выбираем число после символа `-`, и используем его в качестве размера шрифта.